# Using template to display list Items

Tags: css, html-table, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using sencha touch 2.2.1 . I want to display list items in such way that the title of the   item appears on left and its value appears on right. For that I am using itemTpl in which I am using 'table' tag. But the width of the column changes according to the content of the column irrespective of the width given to the columns.

Please find my code below:

```
   {
            xtype: 'list',
            flex: 1,
            ui: 'round',
            data:[
                { title:'Descriptions', text: 'Change MP3 System'},
                { title:'Priority', text: 'Very High'},
                { title: 'Change Coord', text: 'Eudes Canuto'},
                { title: 'Target Data', text: '20.08.2013'},
                { title: 'LOB', text: 'Electronice'},
                { title: 'Major Change', text: 'Yes'},
                { title:'Risk', text: 'High'}
            ],
            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<table style="border:1px solid black; border-spacing: 10px;">',
                        '<tpl for=".">',
                            '<tr>',
                                '<td style="border:1px solid black;padding: 30px;">{title}</td>',
                                '<td style="border:1px solid black;padding: 30px;">{text}</td>',
                            '</tr>',
                        '</tpl>',
                    '</table>'                      
            )
        }
```

Is there any other way to specify the width of the columns so that the content will get adjusted with equal spacing inside the column irrespective of its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use tables in your template. It is much easier to format your items with divs. Tables are for tabular data (ie. like a spreadsheet), not layouts.